# How can I update a hash value using a hash reference in Perl?

Tags: perl, hash, hashref, hash-reference

Is there a way to update a value in a hash using a hash reference that points to the hash value?

My hash output looks like this:

```
    'Alternate' => {
        'free' => '27.52',
        'primary' => 'false',
        'used' => '0.01',
        'name' => '/mydir/journal2',
        'size' => '50.00'
     },
    'Primary' => {
        'free' => '60.57',
        'primary' => 'true',
        'used' => '0.06',
        'name' => '/mydir/journal',
        'size' => '64.00'
    }
};
```

I attempted to create a hash reference to the 'used' property in the hash and tried to update the value:

```
$hash_ref = \%hash->{"Primary"}->{used};
$hash_ref = "99%";
print $$hash_ref, "\n";
```

This changes the value of the hash, but I get the "Using a hash as a reference is deprecated at line X". I'd like to know if what I'm trying to do is possible and what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: To access the 'used' key you would do something like this
$hash->{Primary}->{used} or $hash{Primary}->{used} (depending on whether your outer structure is a hash-ref or a hash). This will return the value 0.06, not a reference. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 4):

```
 ...
'Primary' => {
    'free' => '60.57',
    'primary' => 'true',
    'used' => '0.06',
    'name' => '/mydir/journal',
    'size' => '64.00'
}
 ...
```

Try to bypass the deprecation problem doing it like this:

```
 ...
my $hash_ref = $hash{'Primary'}; # if you declared `%hash = ( .. );`
# Or my $hash_ref = $hash->{'Primary'}; if you declared `$hash = { .. };`
print $hash_ref->{used}; # Prints 0.06
$hash_ref->{used} = '0.07'; # Update
print $href->{used}; # Prints 0.07
 ...
```

See [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html), if you want to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

Your failure started because you tried to create a hash reference to a scalar. That's kind of a meaningless goal as those are different data types. As [Filippo already demonstrated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22300342/how-can-i-update-a-hash-value-using-a-hash-reference-in-perl/22300729#22300729), you already have hash references as values of your greater hash, so you can rely on that.

However, if you really want to create a reference to the scalar, you can just edit that value. This is how you'd do it:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $h = {
    'Alternate' => {
        'free' => '27.52',
        'primary' => 'false',
        'used' => '0.01',
        'name' => '/mydir/journal2',
        'size' => '50.00',
     },
    'Primary' => {
        'free' => '60.57',
        'primary' => 'true',
        'used' => '0.06',
        'name' => '/mydir/journal',
        'size' => '64.00',
    }
};

my $primary = $h->{Primary};
print $primary->{used}, "\n"; # Outputs 0.06

my $usedref = \$h->{Primary}{used};
$$usedref = '0.07';

print $primary->{used}, "\n"; # Outputs 0.07
```